# if statemtent with error I never seen

Tags: r, if-statement

I don't understand this error:

```
Warning message:
In if ((t$carried2 == t$Dead5) & (t$carried2 == t$Dead6)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

my piece of code:

```
if ((t$carried2 == t$Dead5) & (t$carried2 == t$Dead6)) {(t$Dead5 = 0) & (t$Dead6 = 0)}
```

This is probably crappy, but I am new. Anyways, I want to say if (this and that happen) {then this and that = 0

Comment: What are you trying to get as a result?  `if` is probably not the best choice.

Comment: A place to start is to read `?Logic` carefully on the differences between `&` and `&&`.

Comment: I have a large data set and I have data in some columns that are counted twice and want to clean it up, what would you recommend if I have two conditions an when these conditions are meet then this must happen?

Comment: -1 for not searching. This has been asked/answered several times.

Comment: @ Joshua, I actually did alot of searching, since last Friday and this never appeared in my search engine. I would be glad to show you.

Comment: I don't know what search terms you used, but searching for the exact warning/error usually results in several hits. For example: ["the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%22the+condition+has+length+%3E+1+and+only+the+first+element+will+be+used%22).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
indices <- (t$carried2 == t$Dead5) & (t$carried2 == t$Dead6)

t$Dead5[indices] <- 0
t$Dead6[indices] <- 0
```

This sets the the values of `t$Dead5` and `t$Dead6` to zero, in those rows where the condition is `TRUE`.

You say in your comment that you want to clean up the data frame.  Here is how you remove the rows for which `indices` is `TRUE`.  With `indices` as above:

```
t <- t[!indices,]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `if` clause in R expects a single boolean value: TRUE or FALSE.

By using `&` you're returning a vector of booleans, that's the cause of warning:

> ...only the first element will be used

So it will pick the first boolean and use it to test the if-else.

You may want to look at `ifelse` which works like a 'vectorized' `if-else` operator.
Also look at the differences between `&` and `&&`:

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.

Comment: @ Fernando, this was a great lesson you presented. THanks